Why do all the flower that come out on my Rhododendron never fully open? All the light purple flowers show up but never completely open up
All the light purple flowers show up every year like other plant in the yard but none of the flowers completely open up like they are glued shut. This has been happening for years. The bush had flowered fully a number of years ago but doesn't any longer.

Please [edit] to add pictures.

@Jerry please heed the above comment! @ everyone a bit too rough of a reason to close a question, no? Especially from a new contributor. With a multi-upvoted question.

@Vorac This question is being discussed on Meta.  https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/998/why-was-this-answerable-and-answered-question-closed-for-lack-of-detail-and-clar

I find various possible causes listed for Rhododendrons aborting flowers (different from not making buds in the first place) with nutrient deficiencies, frost or cold damage, and insufficient water topping the list.
Magnesium in particular is mentioned as a deficiency that might cause this behavior.
Frost damage resulting from fertilizing too late the fall before (causing lush growth into fall frosts without hardening off) is also mentioned.
